# Can microdialysis be made in Drosophila melanogaster?

Tags: lab-techniques, drosophila

I've asked this before in stack overflow's cognitive science community, and someone recommended me to ask here:

I've found a couple of studies using microdialysis on insects, but didn't found any in *Drosophila*. I've found that the membrane diameter are from 240um, and it seems that *Drosophila melanogaster* brain must be between 200-300um , but I was wondering if the lack of studies of perfused drugs in *Drosophila* is due to this technical constraint, or is just I'm searching wrongly.

--
Edit: I specified the original target, *Drosophila melanogaster*, since there are bigger parients like Hawaian *D. heteroneura* and *D. cyrtoloma*. that could be subject to MD with current probes.

Comment: This is a great question! I was not aware microdialysis was used in *Drosophila* since most use feeding (compounds dissolved in *Drosophila* food) to administer different drugs to *Drosophila*. Is the microdialysis used on the adult *Drosophila* or larvae? why not inject the larvae?

Comment: @Bez , I didn't find microdialysis use in Drosophila but I thought that maybe it could be made on heteroneura and cyrtoloma since they are bigger, that's what I meant to say :P sorry for the missleading comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly unlikely to me. The smallest microdialysis probes I've ever seen are about 250 µm in diameter, so about the size of a Drosophila hemisphere. You can deliver drugs by microinjection (well, I assume you can, seeing as a) you can do it in honey bees and b) you can perform whole-cell patch clamp recordings in Drosophila).